# marginalization of joint distributions

Tags: joint-distribution, marginal-distribution

I am trying to understand the following sentence, section 2.2, in this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1602.05473.pdf):

"...it is required that the joint mode $p(x,z,a)$ gives back the original $p(x,z)$ under marginalization over $a$, thus $p(x,z,a) = p(a|x,z)p(x,z)...$"

Generally,

$$p(x,z)=\int p(x,z,a) \ da.$$

So, what is the reason to specify the above factorization? to avoid taking the above integral, which might be intractable? or to avoid to specify a full factorization of the joint density?

**UPDATE:**
I think the factorization has to do with the theory in Appendix A, and the paper about auxiliar variables (fig 1 and 2) [paper2](http://aivalley.com/Papers/textVAUX_icn.pdf). But it will be nice if someone can shed some light.

Comment: Could you provide a link to the paper and/or give some more background?